# Hierarchy of models while designing a client for a RESTful service

Tags: java, c#, design, design-patterns, object-oriented

I am trying to write a client for a restful service. I am confused in designing the models. Below are the details:

I have a Model named `UnicastMessageRequest`, it's definition is like this:

```
    public class/abstract-class/interface UnicastMessageRequest
    {
        public string tId { get; set; }
        public IDictionary<string, object> tVariables { get; set; }
        [JsonConverter(typeof(Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.StringEnumConverter))]
        public CommunicationMedium communicationMedium { get; set; }
        public IList<MessageAttachment> messageAttachments { get; set; }
        public string to { get; set; }
    }
```

I am not sure about making this class as a concrete class or abstract class or an interface, so right now I wrote the type as `class/abstract class/interface`.

This above model has the properties which I need to send as a body in an HTTP post request.

Now, I am performing different functions like `sending email`, `sending SMS` or `sending WhatsApp message` by hitting the same HTTP end point which needs the above defined `UnicastMessageRequest` model as the body of the request.

So, for convenience, I was thinking to write Wrapper data models for `Email request`, `WhatsApp request` and `SMS request`.

properties like `tId`, `tVariables` `communicationMedium` and `to` is necessary for all the request body, but `messageAttachment` isn't necessary.

Example of a EmailRequest model:

```
public class EmailRequest
{
    public string tId { get; set; }
    public IDictionary<string, object> tVariables { get; set; }
    [JsonConverter(typeof(Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.StringEnumConverter))]
    public CommunicationMedium communicationMedium { get; set; }
    public IList<MessageAttachment> messageAttachments { get; set; }
    public string to { get; set; }
}
```

Example of a SMSRequest model:

```
public class EmailRequest
{
    public string tId { get; set; }
    public IDictionary<string, object> tVariables { get; set; }
    [JsonConverter(typeof(Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.StringEnumConverter))]
    public CommunicationMedium communicationMedium { get; set; }
    public string to { get; set; }
}
```

Here `messageAttachments` isn't required at all.
Similarly, I have a `WhatsAppRequest` model. All these request model needs to be finally converted into the UnicastMessageRequest so that they can call a common API something like:

`SendUnicastMessage(UnicastMessageRequest request)`

How to design it the best way?